# How can you use images in a list of objects and use them in react?

Tags: reactjs

I imported pictures into my portfolio component and used each of them as a property in a list of objects. But when I try to send them over as a prop, the image disappears, and instead shows up as a missing picture. If I made an image tag with the pictures within the component I import them in, they appear just fine. But when I pass them as a prop, that's when they disappear. I import them in a Portfolio component, and try to send them as a prop in a Project component. Someone said earlier to not try to pass an object to a src attribute, and instead try to send the image url as a prop, but if I'm using a the map function to go through each element, I'm not sure how I can send each image URL.

Here is a few of the imports in the Portfolio component:

```
import video_player from "../../images/portfolioImages/video_player.png";
import weather_app from "../../images/portfolioImages/weather_app.png";
```

Here is a bit of the array of objects:

```
const projects = [
  {
    name: "Real-Time-Chatroom",
    type: "Web Page",
    description:
      "Discord-like webpage that allows for several different users to send messages to a variety of different servers/chatrooms.",
    picture: { chatroom },
  },
  {
    name: "Weather App",
    type: "Web Page",
    description:
      "Weather application that uses user's location to find the correct weather, and display that information on screen, with CSS styling that changes depending on the weather conditions of the user's area.",
    picture: { weather_app },
  },
];
```

And here is my Projects component code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Project.css";

const Project = ({ name, type, description, image }) => {
  return (
    <div className="project">
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <img src={image} alt={name}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

Comment: show how you call the `Project` component in `Portfolio`

Comment: Oops, forgot about that part. Here it is:                                                                   const Portfolio = () => {
  return (
    <div id="portfolio">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="projectContainer">
          {projects.map((project) => (
            <Project
              name={project.name}
              type={project.type}
              description={project.description}
              image={project.picture}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};